# How to use P2P in Spotify App (WebRTC?)

Tags: javascript, spotify, p2p, webrtc, spotify-app

In order to exchange information between users of Spotify which installed an app I'm developing I want to be able to set-up a simple P2P connection between Spotify clients (so using JS). Right now I'm using PeerJS because of the ease of use, however, I don't really mind a using different library.

Using PeerJS I tried to set up a connection to the PeerJS server, however, this doesn't work. PeerJS tells me a connection could not be made because WebRTC is not supported by the browser (which is some version of Chrome). Is there a different method of setting up a connection between clients (and how?), or do I have to run everything through a server?

Comment: Native P2P API in browsers is still very experimental.

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#browser-capabilities tells us the embedded Chrome is v29, so whatever you develop will need to take that into account.

Comment: Hmm, but I've seen elsewhere the CEF3 is used in Spotify and it seems WebRTC is fixed in CEF3 later builds.  Maybe they'll update their CEF at some point, but I'd say you're probably out of luck at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I will go and figure out how to do this another way. If anyone has suggestions, be sure to spill them :).